# iPhone X WKWebView scroll stuck

Tags: ios, scroll, wkwebview, iphone-x

I have an application that opens a WKWebView. in all iPhones and Android devices the scroll works well, but only in iPhone x the scroll is stuck when the height of content is longer than the iPhone height in a few px.
I don't have any idea what code did the issue. (obj-c, jquery or the css)

Comment: share your code snippet will help us to understand

Comment: Check content size of scrollView, if it's bigger then frame then scroll would work